# SQL table ORDER BY (empty fields at bottom)

Tags: sql, isnullorempty, sql-order-by

I have a question about ordering my SQL table. I've already tried several things but I can't find the solution that I want.

My table looks as follows:

```
username  childs+pets  childs    pets
=======================================
Max       1                      1
Nico      3            1         2       
Lewis     2            2        
Daniel    2            1         1
```

I want to order my table by childs+pets (ASCending), but I want to put the records with empty fields (Max and Lewis) at the bottom of the table. Which results in:

```
username  childs+pets  childs    pets
=======================================
Nico      3            1         2
Daniel    2            1         1       
Lewis     2            2        
Max       1                      1
```

Who can help me?

Comment: You say empty fields, does that mean NULL's? (Or zero length strings...)

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. The answer may use product specific functionality,

Comment: Zero length strings. And dmbs is MariaDB.

Comment: Why not integer, and null?

Comment: Do you realize that you have set your sample result set on an child+pets DESCending order instead of ASCending order ? :-)

Comment: I changed it into NULL, it works better. Thanks.

Comment: You're right Marc :-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution that works in SQL Server. I've also assumed that Childs+Pets is a calculated field from the two separate fields.

Test Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Username nvarchar(10), Childs int, Pets int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (Username, Childs, Pets)
VALUES
('Max',NULL,1)
,('Nico', 1,2)
,('Lewis',2,NULL)
,('Daniel',1,1)
```

Query

```
SELECT
    td.Username
    ,COALESCE(td.Childs,0) + COALESCE(td.Pets,0) Childs_Pets --The coalesce returns a Zero if the field contains a NULL
    ,td.Childs
    ,td.Pets
FROM #TestData td
ORDER BY CASE WHEN td.Childs IS NULL OR td.Pets IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC
,COALESCE(td.Childs,0) + COALESCE(td.Pets,0) ASC
```

Output

```
Username    Childs_Pets     Childs      Pets
Daniel      2               1           1
Nico        3               1           2
Max         1               NULL        1
Lewis       2               2           NULL
```

The `CASE` statement gets ordered first so if anything has a NULL value in either `Childs` or `Pets` then it will be pushed to the bottom. The ordering of `Childs_Pets` comes after and sorts `ASC` as you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I changed the empty fields to NULL and this works.

Answer (score 0):

The sample is not clear enough, so choose one of the two:

```
select      *

from        t

order by    "childs+pets" + 0  desc
           ,case when childs = '' then 2 else 1 end
           ,case when pets   = '' then 2 else 1 end
;
```

---

```
select      *

from        t

order by    case when childs = '' then 2 else 1 end
           ,case when pets   = '' then 2 else 1 end
           ,"childs+pets" + 0 desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (works for Null values) is just :

```
select * 
from mytable
order by coalesce(childs+pets, 9999)
```

Alternatively, as you say that your empty values are zero strings, you can also use :

```
select * 
from mytable
order by case when childs = '' or pets = '' then '9999' else childs+pets end
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least inform OP and the rest of us which dbms it is for.

Comment: You are right, I have changed the isnull function for the coalesce function, so now this is plain ANSI SQL 92 and should work on any modern dbms.

Comment: Doesn't guarantee to return the OP requested results

Comment: Does it matter ?, you know the values you are storing on those fields so you can set whatever boundary value that you know in real life will never be exceeded.

Comment: Thank you for your help!